# Adding keyboard shortcut to a blender script

Tags: python, scripting, video-sequence-editor

I know it's probably not the most elegant, or even a usable, solution, but is it possible to use a keyboard shortcut, say <kbd>pageUP</kbd> in a python blender script?

**OR** find out the code behind the shortcut, like one can do elsewhere in blender, like a button's code for example.

I have been looking in the input user preferences and hovered over the shorcut , which gives me:

```
keyMapItem.map_type
bpy.data.window_managers["WinMan"] ... map_type
```

But i'm not sure how to use this, in a script, to give me the shortcut "page up" functionality.

Comment: What is "blender script"? Is it the Text editor or Python console or is this about adding a shortcut with python script? What function you want to make a shortcut for?

Comment: I don't think you want to use the shortcut, you want to use the tool that the shortcut activates.

Comment: I have a series of  one frame movie strips, which I want to iterate through and extend each strip from one frame to 10 frames. I use the pageUP and pageDpwn shortcut to manually iterate through them, then select them and change the length from one to ten. I was looking to automate this process with a python script within Blender.

Comment: I cannot find the syntax that relates to the shortcut. I know to hover over a button, or whatever, to get the python code, but am stuck for shortcuts.

Comment: @reggie Go to the user preferences > INPUT and search for "Page Up" with the mask set to Key Binding

Comment: I think your going about this the wrong way. Like Ray Mairlot said, you don't want the buttons pushed, you want some action to take place. That's why I replace your question with the comment above. You want to iterate through the strips and extend them to ten frames. This has nothing to do with buttons if you're trying to achieve this with code.

Comment: I re edited the question to try and make it simpler, but may have confused the issue! I failed to say that there are other movie strips in the scene that I don't want to change. I only want to change the movie strips that are 1 frame long.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be better(and probably easier) to do this directly rather than using trying to use the keyboard shortcuts in the code. Try this:

```
seqs = bpy.context.scene.sequence_editor.sequences_all
for seq in seqs:
    seq.frame_final_duration = 10
```

Or if you want to just modify selected strips:

```
seqs = bpy.context.scene.sequence_editor.sequences_all
for seq in seqs:
    if seq.select:
        seq.frame_final_duration = 10
```

Or if you want to just modify the strips based in their length:

```
seqs = bpy.context.scene.sequence_editor.sequences_all
for seq in seqs:
    if seq.frame_final_duration == 1:
        seq.frame_final_duration = 10
```

Comment: I was trying to use the shortcut to jump through my clips in the scene, so I could select the clips that are only one frame long. I have other longer clips in there too, sorry didn't make myself clear.

Comment: Your answer is spot on for my comment (3rd comment down)!

Comment: Could your code be modified to only select the clips that are 1 frame long and ignore the others?

Comment: Added to answer.

Comment: Whoo, this does what I need! Thanks cmomney.  I'm a little curious, however, if one can actually use shortcut keys in some way in a script?

Comment: Again, its not the shortcut key your after, its the operator or function that the shortcut is performing. And yes, you can reproduce just about everything you can do with buttons and keys with code. If my answer solves your problem please choose it as the answer.

Comment: I'll up-vote your answer if you can add how to assign a keyboard hotkey to run the script.